# Group results from foreach by a var from the string

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I get following results from my query:

**Techn1**

- p1 some text

**Techn2**

- p22 some text

**Tech3**

- p1 some other text

**Techn2**

- p52 some text

**Techn2**

- p62 some text

I want to group the result by Tech# in a way that the result would be

**Techn1**

- p1 some text

**Techn2**

- p22 some text
- p52 some text
- p62 some text

**Tech3**

- p1 some other text

This is the used code :

```
$vars = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'actualite'));
        while ( $vars->have_posts() ) : $vars->the_post();
        $child_posts = types_child_posts("contenu");    
        foreach ($child_posts as $child_post) :
                    if($child_post->fields['theme']=='A'):
                    $technique =$child_post->fields['f1'];
                        if (@$lastTechnique != $technique):
                            print "<strong>".$technique."</strong><br>";
                        endif;                              
                            echo "- ".$child_post->fields['f2']." Some text : ".$child_post->fields['f3']." (some text : ";the_title();echo ")<br>";
                    else:
                        echo "";
                    endif;
                endforeach;
        endwhile;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$vars = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'actualite'));
$techniques = [];
while ( $vars->have_posts() ) : 
    $vars->the_post();
    $child_posts = types_child_posts("contenu");    
    foreach ($child_posts as $child_post) :
        if($child_post->fields['theme']=='A'):
            $technique =$child_post->fields['f1'];
            if (!isset($techniques[$technique]))
            {
                $techniques[$technique] = [];
            }
            $techniques[$technique][] = "- ".$child_post->fields['f2']." Some text : ".$child_post->fields['f3']." (some text : " . get_the_title() . ")<br>";
        endif;
    endforeach;
endwhile;
foreach ($techniques as $technique=>$childTexts):
    print "<strong>".$technique."</strong><br>";
    foreach (array_unique($childTexts) as $childText):
        print $childText;
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

Comment: Dear Evan, thx for the try out. It returns much more results than expected because many result rows are copied several times in your output. There must be something wrong with the places where the foreach are placed in the code.

Comment: Can you show me the output now?  Did you use the first or second example?

Comment: I used both examples and removed the_title(). Even then the results are copied several times.

Comment: Sorry you were right about the placement of the foreach.  It's fixed now.

Comment: Evan, you ROCK!!! You made my day. Thanks a lot. Do you have any experience in WordPress? I am trying to get ONLY the posts (post_type=post) having for the custom field "theme" the value "A". The custom field "theme" is part of custom post "contenu" which is a child of post_type=post. The custom field "theme" is part of a Custom Fields Group called Contenudata (group_id=750). The code above is a workaround which 1) get all the posts from post_type=post and 2) check which has "theme"="A". This workaround is to heavy. Any idea how to directly select ONLY the posts with custom field "theme ="A".?

Comment: Awesome man I just regret the initial error in my fix.  I am not a wordpress expert and tbh I dislike it quite a bit.  As far as your other question, you should start a separate question and I or someone can chime in.